# SequelizeConnectionError Unable to connect to the database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I have `RDS db instance of class db.t2.micro` with 18 connections active as `RDS db instance of class db.t2.micro` have maximum 66 connection but i am facing this issue

> Unable to connect to the database: { [SequelizeConnectionError:
>   remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser
>   and rds_superuser connections]

Answer (score 0):

select all conenctions, not just active.

[according to docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html)

> max_connections (integer) Determines the maximum number of concurrent
>   connections to the database server. The default is typically 100
>   connections, but might be less if your kernel settings will not
>   support it (as determined during initdb). This parameter can only be
>   set at server start.
>
> When running a standby server, you must set this parameter to the same
>   or higher value than on the master server. Otherwise, queries will not
>   be allowed in the standby server.